# Have I removed too much content with my edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

I just [revised this answer suggesting shFlags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/867488/revisions) yet I am bit unsure if I went too far in removing content. Since my edits do not go through the review queue anymore, I want to get feedback if such edits are indeed wanted.

My thinking was that the first paragraph distracted from the answer, which in the end is about introducing shFlags and its usage and now this is the first thing the readers gets to see.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that this edit was a bit much.  The context of introducing the new suggestion as opposed to sticking with what the OP had been using is lost, and is definitely desired here.

It probably *was* one of those, "Hey, use this thing instead!" answers, but without that context, it comes across as one even *more* so.

Answer (score 1):

### In general...

You need to use common sense. If you have:

- Changed so much that it is asking something different altogether.
- Deleted things that were important / needed to answer the question.
- Reworded it just for the sake of editing it.

Than yes, your edits were unnecessary / too much. However if you have:

- Formatted code, link, titles, etc.
- Fixed the OP's grammar.
- Spaced out the text / added paragraphs.

Or otherwise improved the post than no, good job!

Just ask yourself those questions, use common sense and all will be fine!